# conda install error with scanpy from the bioconda channel

Tags: conda, scanpy

I am trying to install package through conda. However, it keeps saying error message (below). If anyone knows how to solve this issue, please let me know!

```
C:\Users\cjh81>conda install -c bioconda scanpy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining @/win-64::__cuda==10.1=0: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  4.48it/s]-failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==10.1=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==10.1=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.1
```

Comment: This is an issue with the repository you are trying to install from. I just tested the install you are trying on a know functional system and it failed the same way. You should raise the issue with the package maintainer. For example https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/issues/990

Comment: bioconda supports macOS and linux, but not Windows. That's not an issue with upstream.

Comment: @cal: I get an identical error on a miniconda3 install on linux, so I don't believe that is the problem

Comment: `conda create -n testfoo -c bioconda -c conda-forge scanpy --dry-run` works for me on both linux and macOS - maybe the conda-forge channel is not available via .condarc?

Comment: @Chris, can you try `conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge scanpy`?